# Fixing a syntax error and rendering not showing with RayWenderlich Metal part 2 tutorial

Tags: swift, metal

I am trying to learn Metal when all of a sudden I get hit with a syntax error. I was wondering why the person tried to add an UnsafeMutablePointer, but that is beside the point. I tried moving the stuff so it doesn't try to add an int to and UnsafeMutablePointer, but the cube just outright disappears.

This tutorial seems to have a programming syntax error and moving the cause into a different parameter or this doesn't help at all (it erases everything). (This isn't because of updates to the language).

The Gitlab to the project (I am going to keep it to one file) and the problem is at around 67. Here is what the code looks like :

```
memcpy(bufferPointer + MemoryLayout<Float>.size * Matrix4.numberOfElements(), projectionMatrix.raw(), MemoryLayout<Float>.size * Matrix4.numberOfElements())
```

Here is the Gitlab link if you want a closer look at the whole file for context:

```
        let bufferPointer = uniformBuffer?.contents()
        memcpy(bufferPointer, nodeModelMatrix.raw(), MemoryLayout<Float>.size * Matrix4.numberOfElements())

        //come back to here
        memcpy(bufferPointer + MemoryLayout<Float>.size * Matrix4.numberOfElements(), projectionMatrix.raw(), MemoryLayout<Float>.size * Matrix4.numberOfElements())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a subtle change in the Metal API that happened circa Swift 4 and iOS 11.

The return type of the `-newBufferWithLength:options:` method changed from `nonnull id<MTLBuffer>` to `nullable id<MTLBuffer>`. As a result, the return type of the corresponding `makeBuffer(length:options:)` method in the Swift "overlay" changed from `MTLBuffer` to `MTLBuffer?`

Therefore, if you use optional chaining with a value returned by this API, the `contents()` method returns an `UnsafeMutableRawPointer?`, rather than what you want, which is an `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`. If you instead use force-unwrapping to ensure that you get a non-nil buffer from the device, all of the pointer arithmetic type-checks just fine.

A couple of extra points:

- This is not a syntax error in the [original article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/728-metal-tutorial-with-swift-3-part-2-moving-to-3d), but the result of migrating Swift 3 code to Swift 4 without fully accounting for API changes.
- It's perfectly valid to add an `Int` to an `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`: it offsets into the pointer by that number of bytes, producing another `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`.

Comment: To sum it up. Optionals don't really help in this case since Swift needs facts to add to the UnsafeMutableRawPointer? As it doesn't know whether the thing would be there or not, which is especially important when rendering a object?

Comment: It's hypothetically possible for buffer creation to fail, and the API is now designed to reflect that. You can either handle the rare case where you don't get a buffer back (e.g., when the device is out of memory), or just abort the program (via force-unwrap), since if you're out of memory, there are probably other things going wrong anyway.